# Writing a batch script to rename filename based on two strings found in content

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have multiple `Invoice_Term1........txt` files in a directory, e.g. `Invoice`. The content of each of file contains:

```
Invoice No : B23335 ...  
Account Code : ABDU16 ...
```

How do I loop through each txt file, `FINDSTR Invoice No :` , but copy `B23335` and `FINDSTR Account Code :` , and copy `ABDU16`?

Concerns are that each `Invoice No` and `Account Code` are different in character length and there are other words after the number and code strings, *(represented as `...` in my above example content)*, separated from it with a space character.

The intention is to rename the files, using the above example, to `Invoice_Term1.......B23335_ABDU16.txt`.

I tried using AI, but definitely need a lot of changes, or even a full rewrite.

```bash
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN (*.txt) DO (
    FINDSTR /R /C:"Invoice No :" /C:"Account Code :" \"%%F\" > temp.txt
    SET /P KEYWORD1=<temp.txt
    SET /P KEYWORD2=<temp.txt
    FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%A IN ("%KEYWORD1%") DO (
        FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%B IN ("%KEYWORD2%") DO (
            REN \"%%F\" %%A%%B.txt
        )
    )
    DEL temp.txt
)
```

I need some expert assistance.

Comment: Issue 1: Beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947) ('keyword?` being changed within loop). Issue 2: `temp.txt` will contain (at least) 2 lines if both elements are present. `set /p var=<temp.txt` will assign the first of these to the variable.

Comment: If the delimiter is a space the TOKEN would be 4 based on your examples.

Comment: What is the `.......` in your file names? It would certainly help us if you try to be realistic and representative with the secret parts of your file and or directory names. BTW, `REN \"%%F\"` should be `REN "%%F"`, and `%%A%%B` would surely need to be `%%A_%%B`.

Comment: You should consider debugging you code one line at a time.  Start with one line of code. In your case, the first FOR command that gets a list of files in the current working directory.  Echo that output to validate.  Keep adding a line and echoing the output. Fix the code before adding another line. You would have caught most of these mistakes if you would just debug your own code first. Always debug from the running the script from the cmd prompt with ECHO ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-4" %%g IN ("%%e") DO (
  IF /i "%%g%%h%%i"=="InvoiceNo:" SET "Inv=%%j"
  IF /i "%%g%%h%%i"=="AccountCode:" SET "Account=%%j"
 )
 ECHO REN "%%e" "%%~ne!Inv!_!Account!.txt"
)

popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Noting that `Invoice No : B23335` is in the before-file and `B233335` is in the desired new name (one extra `3` - presumed typo)

It is important to specify the form of `......` since the presence of, eg. spaces in the filename may affect the code that's required to process it.

Note that renaming a file to samefilenameplusextracharacters.ext is likely to cause `for…(mask)…` to reprocess the file. The `for /f…('dir…` method builds the filelist first in memory, then processes the filelist.

Switch directories [**pushd**]

`dir /b /a-d` produces a list of filenames-only.

Read each line from file, Butt-up the first 3 tokens as, eg. `Invoice` `No` `:` for testing and grab the fourth token (using the default delimiters) for the variables.

Switch back to original directory [**popd**]

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Comment: the reason for ....... is because all these text files can be generated by any names.  
i would make sure no space or other special char involve.  

i tried your recommended script and there is an error  
" %e IN ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') DO ( was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Fixed - `delims="` should be `"delims="` (this means 'assign the entire line to the metavariable` [%%e] - there are no delimiters) and should also ensure that spaces in the name are OK.

Comment: its almost working. REN "Invoice_Term32021-2022_Part26.txt" "Invoice_Term32021-2022_Part26B23335_ABDU16.txt" is shown but filename has not been renamed.

Comment: sorry but i dont get you. when i run your script, it ECHO that REN line that i posted but filename was not changed.
what i tried was to copy the same REN line and run it manually and the REN works.

Comment: That's exactly, what the last paragraph tells you: the `ren` command is "disabled" by just echoing it (for safety reasons, to not do things before you had a chance to verify it's exactly what you want). Once you verified, the `ren` command will do what you want, just remove the `ECHO` in front of it to actually enable the `ren` command. Just as the last paragraph says.

Comment: ahhhh i get what you meant.
thank you a lot.
just one last request, i would like to separate the filename with an underscore because currently its joined with new variables

Comment: You mean in your question `Invoice_Term1.......B23335_ABDU16.txt` should read `Invoice_Term1......._B23335_ABDU16.txt`? Come on - this is trivial. Just insert the underscore where you want it.

Comment: Actually, that's what you requested. The change is obvious - `"%%~ne!Inv!_!Account!.txt"` becomes `"%%~ne_!Inv!_!Account!.txt"`. On the lots-of-dots matter, I believe the best way to indicate some random text is to use, eg. `Invoice_Term1somerandomtext.txt` and then to add a note about the structure of  `somerandomtext` as for instance, if it is all-alphabetic, mixed alphanumeric or whatever, with a special mention for any symbols that may be present. The approach used can depend on whether or not spaces or other symbols having a meaning to `cmd` are present.